# ERROR - A transport exception occurred

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-2, raspi-check

I'm trying to get my Pi to automatically test the internet speed using the speedtest-cli.

When I run the command through the terminal itself, it works just fine.

However, I want to run it off my phone with the RasPi Check app for Android.

Any other command works perfectly fine from the phone to the Pi terminal, yet when I try to execute the Python file, it halts and gives me an "ERROR - A transport exception occurred."

The command I'm trying to run via phone is

```
exec /home/pi/speedtest-cli
```

If I use the terminal on the Pi itself, it executes perfectly with that command.

Why is it that my phone won't send this command specifically through?

For example, if I used

```
exec /pi/home/
```

I'll get a return message saying that it is a directory and cannot be executed. But if I try to execute speedtest-cli I get the transport error.

Comment: "Transport" implies something to do with low level networking between the phone and the pi, which I'd guess is not actually the case -- i.e., the app is handling and reporting an error incorrectly, which is a bug in itself, probably caused by the bug that it is incorrectly reporting.

Comment: The phone and the Pi are on the same network, any other code runs just fine even using 'exec' however that one line will not for the life of me go through.

Comment: You could try watching the android system log to see if there is a better explanation there; I use the "system tuner" app for that, I am sure there are many such things.  The log flows very quickly, so you'll probably need to use some kind of filter and/or record it for a short slice of time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later tonight and update you on it

Comment: Is the script trying to determine the ip of the system it is running on? And hence getting a mismatch between the Pi and Phone.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Negative, the script itself is already on the Pi so it will never receive the IP on the phone. The phone is just sending the command line remotely to run it, that is all it is needing to do.

Comment: @goldilocks I got the app but totally forgot to update you on it. RasPi doesn't show up on SystemTuner, and I can't record any logs with it as far as I know.